When is the third expression in a for loop executed?
K.N King Chapter 6, Ex-6
The program I wrote:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    for (int i = 1; i<=128; i *= 2)
        printf("%d\n", i);

}


When this program is executed, since i is 1 and less than 128 it is multiplied by 2. So first expected output is 2, but instead it is 1. Why is that so?

i *= 2 runs after the loop body.

Read the section about for loops again. It explains the order in which the three terms in the for parentheses and the statements in the loop body are evaluated. It has nothing to do with compound assignment specifically.

think of for (init; condition; increment) ... as init; while (condition) {...increment;}, but please read the language definition carefully

When this program is executed, since i is 1 and less than 128 IT IS PRINTED, THEN it is multiplied by 2.

Surely there's some canonical dupe for this somewhere...

What learning material are you using that does not tell this at the very beginning? You need to drop it and get some other learning material.

for (a; b; c) { d; }

is equivalent to
{
    a;
    while (b) {
        d;
        c;
    }
}


Exception: for allows a, b, and c (and d) to be "empty". When b is "empty", use 1 when substituting while eg for (;;) { if (reduce()) break; } ==> while (1) { if (reduce()) break; }

The expressions in for (int i = 1; i<=128; i *= 2) are not evaluated in left-to-right order as if the computer merely scans the text and immediately does each thing. Instead, this text describes a loop structure. The third part inside parentheses is an expression to evaluate after the loop. So, this C code:
for (int i = 1; i<=128; i *= 2)
    printf("%d\n", i);

tells the compiler to construct a representation of a loop like this:

Define an int named i and assign 1 to it.
While i<=128 evaluates as true:

Evaluate the body of the loop, printf("%d\n", i);
After the body of the loop, multiply i by 2 and assign the result to i.



So, when printf is executed in the first iteration of the loop body, i has the value 1, because i *= 2 is not evaluated until after each iteration of the loop body.
